# Do you know how to move elements to first position, without changing other elements order?

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, numbers, move

```cs
 using System;

namespace MoveFirst
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] values = ReadValuesList();
            int[] positionsToMove = ReadPositions();

            for (int i = 0; i < positionsToMove.Length; i++)
                MoveFirst(values, positionsToMove[i]);

            PrintValuesList(values);
            Console.WriteLine(CheckIfSortedAscending(values));
            Console.Read();
        }

        static bool CheckIfSortedAscending(int[] values)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)

                if (values[i - 1] > values[i])
                    return false;

            return true;
        }

        public static void MoveFirst(int[] values, int index)
        {

            var temp = values[0];
            values[0] = values[index];
            values[index] = temp;

        }

        static int[] ReadPositions()
        {
            int positionsNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] positions = new int[positionsNumber];

            for (int i = 0; i < positionsNumber; i++)
                positions[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            return positions;
        }

        static int[] ReadValuesList()
        {
            string[] inputValues = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            int[] values = new int[inputValues.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                values[i] = Convert.ToInt32(inputValues[i]);

            return values;
        }

        static void PrintValuesList(int[] valuesList)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < valuesList.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(valuesList[i] + " ");
            Console.Write('\n');
        }

    }
}
```

This is my whole code, but I have a problem with the result..Can I get some suggestions how to correct the code within the MoveFirst method ?

There are given a series of numbers on a single line, separated by a space. There are N operations to move a string element to the first position.. Each move is specified on one line (the index of the element which has to be moved to the first position), but all other elements of the string remain in the same order.

For example if the user inputs : 1 2 3 4 5 6

1

5

the result should be : **6 2 1 3 4 5**

my result is : 6 1 3 4 5 2

Comment: why not use a `List<int>`instead of an array? Or is using an array part of your assignment?

Comment: that's how I've got the exercise..unfortunately, it has to be an array..

Comment: it´s not enough to move the first, you have to move all items. Start at the last index and push every element one position further until you get at the index of the inserted item.

Comment: With code like this it might be useful to set up a unit test. I.e. Create a small array, call individual small functions with some different data and check the result. Does it correspond with your expectations? Can you read and understand why the tested code did not work as expected? If not, can you test a smaller part? If all else fails, learn how to use the debugger and step thru the code, this lets you check the program state after each individual statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example, using `LinkedList<int>`

**Input**:
1 2 3 4 5 6

2

1

5

**Result**:
6 2 1 3 4 5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MoveFirst
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList<int> values = ReadValuesList();
            int[] positionsToMove = ReadPositions();

            for (int i = 0; i < positionsToMove.Length; i++)
                MoveFirst(values, positionsToMove[i]);

            PrintValuesList(values);
            Console.WriteLine(CheckIfSortedAscending(values));
            Console.Read();
        }

        static bool CheckIfSortedAscending(IEnumerable<int> valuesList)
        {
            var prevValue = int.MinValue;
            foreach (int value in valuesList)
            {
                if (prevValue > value)
                    return false;
                prevValue = value;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public static void MoveFirst(LinkedList<int> values, int index)
        {
            if (index == 0 || index >= values.Count)
                return;
            var node = values.First;
            for (var i = 0; i < index; i++)
                node = node.Next;
            values.Remove(node);
            values.AddFirst(node);
        }

        static int[] ReadPositions()
        {
            int positionsNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] positions = new int[positionsNumber];

            for (int i = 0; i < positionsNumber; i++)
                positions[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            return positions;
        }

        static LinkedList<int> ReadValuesList()
        {
            return new LinkedList<int>(Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse));
        }

        static void PrintValuesList(IEnumerable<int> valuesList)
        {
            foreach (int value in valuesList)
                Console.Write(value + " ");
            Console.Write('\n');
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

`MoveFirst` method for situation when you forced to use array.

```
public static void MoveFirst(int[] values, int index)
{
    if (index == 0 || index >= values.Length)
        return;
    var temp = values[index];
    for (int i = index - 1; i >=0; i--)
        values[i + 1] = values[i];
    values[0] = temp;
}
```